# how to edit an image which is saved by using an editor

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am developing an image editor using canvas and fabric js.

My question is how can I edit an image, which is saved by using an editor. I have to change the extension when saving the image or what?

So please if anyone know about the issue please help me out. Thanx in advance.

Comment: A nice way to get started is to view sources of other image editing packages like https://github.com/Intervention/image

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
            document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (f) {
                    var data = f.target.result;
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                        var oImg = img.set({left: 50, width:100, height:100, top: 100, angle: 00}).scale(0.5);
                        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                        var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'jpeg', quality: 0.8 });

     console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
                document.getElementById('txt').href=dataURL;
});
                 };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
               
                
            });
```

```css
 canvas{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

```html
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
        <input type="file" id="file">
        <a href='' id='txt'>Click Me!!</a>
```